# Quickly merge text frames in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, data-merge

Is there a way to quickly link text frames in InDesign? The only way I know is the one-by-one select the in/out handle on each text frame.

**My use case:** I used data merge to create a merged Indd for a catalog. The items in the catalog are varying length. With autosizing on the text frame, doesn't really space things correctly (some text frames will overlap). I want to link all of the text frames into a single thread, and then delete all but the first text frame. I'd prefer not to go through several hundred frames to thread them one-by-one.

Comment: I believe you'd need scripting. I don't think InDesgin has any build in feature to automate threading of text frames.. No clue if this will work but... [SEE HERE](https://indesignsecrets.com/topic/is-there-a-script-to-combine-selected-frames-as-threaded-text-40)

Comment: This sounds tricky to automatize. You could script it, but (without having seen your layout) the hard thing might be to make the script understand the order you want to merge the text frames in.